# Grab data from [AnyHashable: Any] Push notification

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am trying to parse the **next_question_detail** from the push notification but all are fails:

```
for data in notification.request.content.userInfo {
      print(data)
}
//Output

(key: AnyHashable("next_question_detail"), value: {"question_ar":"مرحبا","question":"hi","id":"5"})
(key: AnyHashable("errorCode"), value: 0)
(key: AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"), value: 1)
(key: AnyHashable("body"), value: )
(key: AnyHashable("userId"), value: 4)
(key: AnyHashable("title"), value: Wit)
(key: AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"), value: 0:1528865771984376%fa33e8cdfa33e8cd)
(key: AnyHashable("aps"), value: {
    alert =     {
        body = "";
        title = Wit;
    };
    badge = 0;
    sound = default;
})




        if let aps = notification.request.content.userInfo["next_question_detail"]! as? NSDictionary {
            print("aps",aps)
        }


        if let data = notification.request.content.userInfo["next_question_detail"] as? [String: String] {
            print("array",data)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using following code -

```
if let userInfo = userInfo as? [String: Any] {
    guard let next_question_detail = userInfo["next_question_detail"] as? [String: Any] else {
            return
       }
    print(next_question_detail)
}
```